# UBUNTU 14.04 LTS - FREEZES - How to Analyse?

Tags: freeze

Yesterday, I update the software in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After that, the desktop freezes after 10 minutes.

I am not using any Proprietary Graphics drivers. For me to analyze this issue, I would like to know where I have to start and what log files I need to look for pin pointing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try by installing the below to fix freezing issue,

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

After installing reboot the machine using,

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My Graphic driver was
sudo lshw -c video 
  *-display               
description: VGA compatible controller 
product: RS780L [Radeon 3000] 
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
       physical id: 5 
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0 
       version: 00 
       width: 32 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0 
       resources: irq:18 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:febe0000-febeffff memory:fea00000-feafffff
After proper update of the it started working.